# calculate average for a defined time

Tags: r, time-series

This should be a fairly simple question but somehow I cannot solve it. How can I calculate mean value of `T_M` for any given `start.time` and `end.time`. I see examples of it using hourly/daily etc but how to calculate for a certain defined time?

```
timetable <- data.frame(Time_M = c( "2013-05-03 13:45:00",
                                    "2013-05-03 13:45:01",
                                    "2013-05-03 13:45:02",
                                    "2013-05-03 13:45:03",
                                    "2013-05-03 13:45:04",
                                    "2013-05-03 13:45:05"),
                        T_M = c(12,10,16,15,13,12))
```

`start.time <- 2013-05-03 13:45:01`

`end.time <- 2013-05-03 13:45:04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R option using `tapply`

```
with(
  timetable,
  tapply(
    T_M,
    Time_M > start.time & Time_M < end.time,
    mean
  )["TRUE"]
)
```

gives

```
TRUE
15.5
```

**Data**

```
timetable <- data.frame(
  Time_M = c(
    "2013-05-03 13:45:00",
    "2013-05-03 13:45:01",
    "2013-05-03 13:45:02",
    "2013-05-03 13:45:03",
    "2013-05-03 13:45:04",
    "2013-05-03 13:45:05"
  ),
  T_M = c(12, 10, 16, 15, 13, 12)
)

start.time <- "2013-05-03 13:45:01"
end.time <- "2013-05-03 13:45:04"
```

Comment: many thanks. the data also contains NA, so I added ```mean,na.rm = TRUE```. This is the right way to deal with NA?

Comment: @Sphinx Yes, `na.rm = TRUE` will help

Answer (score 1):

We can use comparison operators to `subset` the rows of the data, then extract the 'T_M' and get the `mean`

```
timetable$Time_M <- as.POSIXct(timetable$Time_M)
mean(subset(timetable, Time_M > as.POSIXct(start.time) &
        Time_M < as.POSIXct(end.time))$T_M)
#[1] 15.5
```

---

Or this can be done with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
timetable %>%
     filter(between(Time_M, as.POSIXct(start.time), as.POSIXct(end.time))) %>%
     summarise(Mean = mean(T_M))
```